# How to pause or stop an HTML5 Audio element from component.ts

Tags: angular, typescript, html5-audio

I'd like to be able to create a function to stop or pause an HTML from my component.ts file. I'm not seeing any built in methods to pause the audio using the document.getelement

```
<audio controls id="audio-file" >
<source src="sample.wav" type="audio/wav">
</audio>
```

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { DOCUMENT } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { WINDOW } from "../../services/window.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-audio',
  templateUrl: './audio.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./audio.component.css']
})
export class AudioComponent implements OnInit {
  private audio = this.document.getElementById("audio-file")
  constructor(
    @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document,
    @Inject(WINDOW) private window: Window
  ) { }
  ngOnInit() {
  }
stopAudio(){
  this.document.getElementById('audio-file')
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `.pause()` on the audio element.

```
stopAudio() {
  this.audio.pause();
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement

Comment: Inspect the method, check if `private audio = this.document.getElementById("audio-file")` is properly setting the element, maybe you need to move that inside `ngOnInit`.

Comment: thank you! declaring private audio; at the top and setting it in the on init fixed my issue